# How to implement image classification using just convolutional layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make an image classification model that outputs a prediction based on a sliding window. The only way to do that is to have the network's output layer as a Conv2D layer.

Here is my model architecture:

```
inputs = Input((None, None, 3))

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

x = Conv2D(1, kernel_size = (128,128), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(x)
x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
```

From what I've read, a Conv2D layer with kernel_size and strides equal to (1,1) is effectively a Dense layer, but this model doesn't converge, while another model with Dense layers did converge (if you need, I can add the original architecture to the question).

I've done the usual housekeeping - like ensuring all my training data is normalized between 0 and 1, but the loss stays at around 0.6.

Comment: Is it the loss or the *accuracy* that stays at around 0.6?

Comment: Loss stays around 0.6. @desertnaut

Comment: I suggest you check the [YOLO](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-v4-or-yolo-v5-or-pp-yolo-dad8e40f7109) architecture, i.e You Only Look Once